# How to install matplotlib 2.0 beta on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I follow the standard installation procedure for matplotlib on Windows. I type the following commands in my terminal:

```
    > python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
    > python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Then I check my matplotlib version:

```
    > python
    >>> import matplotlib
    >>> matplotlib.__version__
    '1.5.1'
```

Apparently this installation procedure doesn't give me the latest matplotlib version. The latest stable release is '1.5.3'. I would expect to get at least that version.

Even better, I would like to test out the latest beta release: '2.0.0 b4'. What instructions should I type in my terminal to get that version?

Note:

I'm using the following python version:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.5.2 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13)
[MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Comment: Added an edit to get is as a .whl file to save you the trouble of compiling from source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for matplotlib 1.5.3

```
conda update matplotlib
```

for matplotlib-2.0.0b4 use wheels provided [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) :
use the .whl as follows :

```
pip install some-package.whl
```